# Hibernate Data not updating in database

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate 3 in my application there is one scenario where i am inserting two record and updating one record :-

```
  SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory();
        session = sf.openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Collection collection = session.load(Collection.class, "12345");    
        tx.commit();
// using this way i am getting this object from database. 
setCollection(collection);//Here i am setting this object in one POJO class
```

Now in other function

I am getting this object again...

```
Collection collection=getCollection(); //here it is detached
```

Now here first i am saving data in one table using below approach:-

```
 SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory();
            session = sf.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Sms sms=new Sms();
        sms.setMessage(collection.getMesage());
       session.save(sms);
       tx.commit();
       session.flush();
       session.close();
```

Then i am updating and inserting two records in same session

```
SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory();
            session = sf.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Cancel cancel=new Cancel();
        cancel.setMessage(collection.getMesage());
       session.save(cancel);
       session.update(collection);
       tx.commit();
       session.flush();
       session.close();
```

The problem in above code , Here in sms and in cancel table data is saving but update is not working and it is not showing any error also.

Its not happening in every case, sometime it is not updating

Is there any problem with two different sessions ??

Comment: Check the queries being fired when `session.update(collection); tx.commit();` is being called. & if possible paste them here too.

Comment: @RAS sorry ... showSql property is set to false in hibernate-configuration file

Comment: you've for to arrange the pasted code... Separate lines when reaching `;`. This: `Collection collection=openSession();` isn't clear at all, for instance. Help us help you ;).

Comment: Can't you set it to true?

Comment: @RAS Sorry its not possible....

Answer (score 0):

No there is nothing wrong in taking two different session.

Here is what happening in you code:

First you are getting the object from database and closing the session

**Collection collection=openSession(); session.load()....session.close();**

Then you are setting the Collection object.
**setCollection(collection);**

Now it will act a Detached object. If do any transaction.commit after this your object will get committed in database even you are saving some other object, which you are doing in your first part where you are saving the first object.

In the second transaction there nothing to update so its not getting updated.

Comment: That's because you did not updated anything in collection object..
Did you ?
Because I did not find any collection.set() method in your code.

Comment: sorry mukesh i forgot to add that code...yes i am updating that collection object like collection.setStatus("XYZ"); its placed before first commit..

Comment: But you are doing 

**Collection collection=getCollection();**

It means at this point your changes to collection object has been lost, and this object has old data again. I mean the one that is present in database.

Comment: Means i am updating value after getCollection()

Comment: I tried but could not able to recreate the scenario of yours, ideally your program should give **LazyInitializationException**, because you are changing the content of Collection after closing the session. But as you said it is not giving any error.
I need to to see your hbm files and also the full program to solve this.

Comment: -Thanks mukesh , But one question - Actually this is happening some time not in every case.So Lazy Exception should come is every case..if there is a problem in code.

Comment: Did you set any LazyInitialization property in your hibernate.cfg.xml ? Can you verify that ?

Comment: No...i have not set this property